# Get php self and GET variables

Tags: php

```
$from = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

echo /marketing/clients.php?action=sendbook&issue=29

How to get `clients.php?action=sendbook&issue=29` only?
Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: I would say: `echo substr($from, 12);`

Comment: `parse_url` doesn't work with relative URLs (as in his example).

Comment: @Steve ? Worked for me. From the manual: "Partial URLs are also accepted, `parse_url()` tries its best to parse them correctly."

Comment: Manual says no (in the "Notes" section) but I haven't tested myself...

Comment: @Steve - haha nice. Stick my foot in my mouth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$temp = explode("/",$from);
$temp = end($temp);
```

or even easier

```
basename($from);
```

Comment: Like the `basename()`. Good 1 up on me. haha

Comment: I follow the "Special Olympics" rule (though I think it's distasteful). http://photos.commongate.com/11/38441_7dtr2scy8f_l.jpg No hostility intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 // or (if you have to use $from)
 $from = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $url = parse_url($from);
 echo $url['path']."?".$url['query'];
 //or
 $url = explode("/",$from);
 echo $url[1];
```